# Rendering of a full hollow mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rendering, mesh

I have a hollow mesh which is created dynamically. As you can see in the right picture it is a full cylinder. However, as you can see in the left one, it appears open, according to the direction you look at it from. How can I make it look full?(without changing the mesh to be not hollow).
[image]

Comment: I'm taking an educated guess here, but it looks like an issue you with backface culling and your normals may be inverted.  How do you create this object?

http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19325/why-is-my-mesh-inversed-when-imported-to-unity

Comment: I agree with @MartinMazzaDawson about it probably being backface culling. Additionally, if you don't want people to see inside the cylinder, then just invert the tris for the ends of the cylinder so that the tri's face the opposite direction.

Comment: note that mesh ***has only one side***.  this is an absolute basic in 3D engineering.  google 10000 discussions on it.   in a game, if you want a "flat" thing to have BOTH surfaces, you literally have two meshes.  For example, a bucket will have a mesh for the outside and a mesh for the inside. it's the most basic aspect of how 3D works.